# Fail to send erc20 on metamask - BEP-20 Token Transfer Error (Unable to locate corresponding Transfer Event Logs)

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, erc-20, metamask

i have been using my 1st testnet token for 2 months+, all works great, but suddenly in mid August error as per title starts popping up.

So now i cant send this token using metamask to other wallet.
What i've tried but failed:

- increase gas limit
- refresh browser, reset laptop, reset metamask
- create new very basic token (MTK), test sending, works fine.

[image: error with sending 1st testnet token, but transfer of 2nd token works fine.]

error sending PEPE2. only 26% gas limit used, and tx failed.
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xa6a7e7064fd4cf1b0775bc0e8aca1c04d56fa0b19b0a46993a68d68494323515

Ok sending MTK.
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0x5b74d096097cb4da1d29db81ad0dac0db492d40fbe5bca3fac6bc91a132b785e

what is the issue here? how do i fix this? this dont make sense to me.
can somebody try to reproduce this and let me know what is wrong?

1st test token (PEPE2):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract PepeToken is Ownable, ERC20 {
    bool public limited;
    uint256 public maxHoldingAmount;
    uint256 public minHoldingAmount;
    address public uniswapV2Pair;
    mapping(address => bool) public blacklists;

    constructor(uint256 _totalSupply) ERC20("Pepe", "PEPE") {
        _mint(msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }

    function blacklist(address _address, bool _isBlacklisting) external onlyOwner {
        blacklists[_address] = _isBlacklisting;
    }

    function setRule(bool _limited, address _uniswapV2Pair, uint256 _maxHoldingAmount, uint256 _minHoldingAmount) external onlyOwner {
        limited = _limited;
        uniswapV2Pair = _uniswapV2Pair;
        maxHoldingAmount = _maxHoldingAmount;
        minHoldingAmount = _minHoldingAmount;
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) override internal virtual {
        require(!blacklists[to] && !blacklists[from], "Blacklisted");

        if (uniswapV2Pair == address(0)) {
            require(from == owner() || to == owner(), "trading is not started");
            return;
        }

        if (limited && from == uniswapV2Pair) {
            require(super.balanceOf(to) + amount <= maxHoldingAmount && super.balanceOf(to) + amount >= minHoldingAmount, "Forbid");
        }
    }

    function burn(uint256 value) external {
        _burn(msg.sender, value);
    }
}
```

2nd test token contract (MTK):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just realized that in my PEPE2 contract has this check:

```
if (uniswapV2Pair == address(0)) {
    require(from == owner() || to == owner(), "trading is not started");
    return;
}
```

so after i use the setRule() function, i can now transfer token to other addresses.